# AJAX & PHP:GET parameters causing Flickr api key error

Tags: php, ajax

I'm trying to send a URL with aFLickr API key to fetch results for a given photo tag. The Ajax code should return the XML to my browser. However the URL structure with parameters seems to cause a problem in my setup:

```
**the HTML file:**
...
url="api.flickr.com/services/rest/?method=flickr.photos.search&api_key=75564008a468bf8a284dc94bbd176dd8&tags=paris"

request.open("GET","xmlget.php?url=" + url + nocache, true)
...

**the 'xmlget.php' file:**
...
echo file_get_contents($_GET['url']);
...
```

**error:** code="100" msg="Invalid API Key (Key has invalid format)">

the link works fine if tested in the adress bar so there must be a breakdown somewhere when the URL is processed.

i tried wrapping it into `encodeURI` but no luck :(

Note: [related post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5359127/ajax-javascript-xml-adding-dom-elements-to-array-not-working)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `encodeURIComponent` instead of `encodeURI` to actually get that string encoded.

May I make 2 suggestions?

- just pass the search parameters to xmlget.php and do the rest there even if it means having to pass a service type if you are using that generically
- I don't remember what all a Flickr api key gets you, but it's generally a bad thing to post anything called an "api key" in public. In addition to the question, that includes sticking it in javascript that an end user can access.

Comment: Hi jesse, thanks for the suggestion. it doesn't make a difference unfortunately. re api key, it seems that Flickr just need that to get some stats on usage of their API's so i don't think it's a problem. re the other suggestion i might try but for now i'll stick to this approach as i got it from a text book although their example was simpler than mine

Comment: your suggestion worked for me! i did some tweaking i.e. adding URL into a variable then applying the encoding: $search = encodeURIComponent($search). Now the full URL is being processed