# AJAX & Javascript & XML: adding DOM elements to array not working

Tags: javascript, ajax

I am fetching some XML from Flickr and want to parse it based on DOM. can't get my code to work with the following:

```
...
if (this.responseXML != null)
    {
        content = this.responseText.getElementsByTagName('content')
        for (i = 0 ; i < content.length ; i++)
        {
            out += content[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue + '<br />'
        }
        document.getElementById('info').innerHTML = out
        }
...
```

this however returns the full content of the call:

```
...
if (this.responseXML != null)
    {
        document.getElementById('info').innerHTML =
            this.responseText
            }
...
```

which leads me to think that my AJAX code is correct but that i'm doing something wrong in the parsing code

Note: this is related another [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5359056/ajax-phpget-parameters-causing-flickr-api-key-error) althought he problem is a different one

Comment: `content[i].childNodes[0]nodeValue` -- is there intentionally a period left out before `nodeValue`?

Comment: Also, responseText is a string, which doesn't have a method called `getElementsByTagName`.

Comment: Hi Reid, good point re responseText. how could i parse what comes in?

Comment: Use responseXML instead of responseText!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seems to be that you're given a string rather than an XML DOM object. In order to create a XML DOM Object, you'll need to parse the XML string. [This stackoverflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/649614/xml-parsing-in-javascript) has some good code and discussion as to what the best way to parse the XML might be.

Comment: Hi Nicholas, please have a look at my related post for a better idea of where i'm coming from: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5359056/ajax-phpget-parameters-causing-flickr-api-key-error